# Add span to each element of list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this

```
<ul class="example">
    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

The result should be like this

```
<ul class="example">
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Something</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span></span>Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help me.

Comment: So you want to add a `span` tag inside your `a` tags via Javascript?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry for that, I'll read it carefully.

Answer (score 6):

Append a span at the beginning using [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method.

```js
$('ul.example li a').prepend('<span></span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="example">
  <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Then if I want to remove text in <a></a> how can I do?

Comment: @MCN : then use `html()` instead of `prepend()`

Comment: Thank you so much again. You saved my life !

Comment: @MCN : glad to hear that mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` to loop each `a` element and change its `html`. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2032/)

```
$('.example li a').each(function() {
  $(this).html('<span></span>' + $(this).text())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

```
$(".example li a").each(function() {
  $(this).html(function(i, origText){
    return "<span></span>" + origText;
  });
});
```

Here origText contains existing inner elements. Here is the reference [JQuery Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp)

This method is very useful even when you have lot of content inside a div.
Hope that helps :)